# Alerting in case of exceptions

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I developed few services and I would like to be able to react fast in case of a bug or failure. These services expose metrics to prometheus and I get alerts through slack. Logs are available in kibana. I can see bugs and exceptions in logs through kibana but I have te check actively for it. I would like to be rather notified about them.
How would you implement these notification? I'm quite new to this subject and I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spring boot for your micro services  and can use Micrometer
as dependency and create a register the LogbackMetrics bean as below

```
new LogbackMetrics().bind(registry);
```

This will expose the counter of all Log Level : INFO, ERROR, WARN
Then you can use Prometheus Alert Manager and access the metrics inside the alert rules.
Please refer below link.
https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/

You can use this example
https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/doc/examples/simple.yml
You can configure to receive email notification or SMS in case of any errors or exceptions